Warning: Cannot update a component (`HotReload`) while rendering a different component (`MapMenu`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `MapMenu`
i'm having the title error on my adress suggestion bar, here's the code:
import { useState } from "react";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

type Suggestion = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    full_address: string;
}

async function fetchSuggestions(searchText: string, sessionToken: string) {
    const url = new URL('https://api.mapbox.com/search/searchbox/v1/suggest');
    url.searchParams.append('q', searchText);
    url.searchParams.append('language', 'fr');
    url.searchParams.append('limit', '5');
    url.searchParams.append('session_token', sessionToken);
    url.searchParams.append('access_token', process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_API_KEY ?? '');

    const response = await fetch(url);
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
    }
    return response.json();
}

async function handleSearch(searchText: string, sessionToken: string, setSearchSuggestions: (suggestions: Suggestion[]) => void) {
    if (!searchText) {
        setSearchSuggestions([]);
        return;
    }

    setSearchSuggestions([]);

    try {
        const data = await fetchSuggestions(searchText, sessionToken);
        if (data?.suggestions) {
            setSearchSuggestions(data.suggestions);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Search error:', error);
        setSearchSuggestions([]);
    }
}

function handleInputChange(
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, 
    sessionToken: string, 
    setSearchSuggestions: (suggestions: Suggestion[]) => void
) {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setTimeout(() => {
        handleSearch(value, sessionToken, setSearchSuggestions);
    }, 300);
}

export default function MapMenu() {
    const [sessionToken] = useState(uuidv4());
    const [searchSuggestions, setSearchSuggestions] = useState<Suggestion[]>([]);

    return (
        <div className='absolute left-0 top-0 right-0 m-auto mt-2 w-[400px] h-fit p-1 flex flex-col rounded-[24px] pointer-events-auto bg-white shadow- [0px_0px_4px_1px_#00000060]'>
            <div className='w-full h-fit flex flex-row items-center'>
               <div className='w-full h-10 p-1 flex flex-row rounded-full items-center bg-[#eeeeee]'>
                   <svg
                        className='w-[28px] h-[28px] fill-[#888888]'
                        fill="#000000"
                        width="800px"
                        height="800px"
                        viewBox="0 0 256.00098 256.00098"
                        id="Flat"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    >
                        <path d="M232.47656,215.51563l-40.67773-40.67774a96.10791,96.10791,0,1,0-16.97168,16.96973l40.67871,40.67871a12.0001,12.0001,0,1,0,16.9707-16.9707ZM43.99707,116a72,72,0,1,1,72,72A72.08124,72.08124,0,0,1,43.99707,116Z"/>
                    </svg>
                    <input 
                        type='text' 
                        placeholder='Localisation' 
                        className='w-full h-full text-xl bg-transparent outline-none'
                        onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, sessionToken, setSearchSuggestions)}
                    />
                </div>
                <button>
                    <svg
                        className='w-[40px] h-[40px]'
                        fill="#000000"
                        width="800px"
                        height="800px"
                        viewBox="0 0 256 256"
                        id="Flat"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    >
                        <path d="M227.99951,171.99353a12.00028,12.00028,0,0,1-12,12H197.65625a31.98806,31.98806,0,0,1-59.31348,0H39.99951a12,12,0,0,1,0-24h98.34326a31.98806,31.98806,0,0,1,59.31348,0h18.34326A12.00028,12.00028,0,0,1,227.99951,171.99353ZM39.999,95.99255l34.34375.00074a31.988,31.988,0,0,0,59.31348.00024L216,95.99255a12,12,0,0,0-.001-24l-82.34277.001a31.98813,31.98813,0,0,0-59.31348-.00024L40,71.99255h-.00049a12,12,0,0,0-.00049,24Z"/>
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div className='w-full h-fit overflow-hidden rounded-b-[24px]'>
                {searchSuggestions.map((suggestion: Suggestion) => (
                    <div key={suggestion.id} className="flex items-center gap-1 p-1 mt-1 w-full hover:bg-[#eeeeee]">
                        <svg
                            className="w-5 h-5 flex-shrink-0"
                            fill="#000000"
                            width="800px"
                            height="800px"
                            viewBox="0 0 256 256"
                            id="Flat"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        >
                            <path d="M199.99975,220H160.73437c5.17652-4.97607,10.74146-10.70947,16.321-17.126,28.09472-32.30859,42.94433-66.499,42.94433-98.874a92,92,0,0,0-184,0c0,50.01221,34.11963,91.94238,59.18408,116H55.99975a12,12,0,0,0,0,24h144a12,12,0,0,0,0-24Zm-140-116a68,68,0,0,1,136,0c0,33.31055-19.95605,63.36621-36.69824,82.71387a249.0586,249.0586,0,0,1-31.30176,30.17138A249.0053,249.0053,0,0,1,96.698,186.71387C79.95581,167.36621,59.99975,137.31055,59.99975,104Zm68,44a44,44,0,1,0-44-44A44.04978,44.04978,0,0,0,127.99975,148Zm0-64a20,20,0,1,1-20,20A20.02229,20.02229,0,0,1,127.99975,84Z"/>
                        </svg>
                        <div className="flex flex-col w-full min-w-0">
                            <span className="w-full font-bold text-base truncate">{suggestion.name}</span>
                            <span className="w-full text-sm text-gray-600 truncate">{suggestion.full_address}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

whenever i reload the page, and then input first character on my input bar, i get these errors:
(1)
_1c1d36._.js:1058 Cannot update a component (`HotReload`) while rendering a different component (`MapMenu`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `MapMenu`, follow the stack trace as described in https://react.dev/link/setstate-in-render Error Component Stack
    at MapMenu (_1c1d36._.js:997:202)
    at div (<anonymous>)
    at div (<anonymous>)
    at Map (exports-mapbox.ts:56:16)
    at Map (map.tsx:34:31)
    at main (<anonymous>)
    at Sdui (sdui.tsx:23:31)
    at main (<anonymous>)
    at Home [Server] (<anonymous>)
    at InnerLayoutRouter (layout-router.tsx:324:3)
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (redirect-boundary.tsx:48:5)
    at RedirectBoundary (redirect-boundary.tsx:79:9)
    at NotFoundErrorBoundary (not-found-boundary.tsx:33:5)
    at NotFoundBoundary (not-found-boundary.tsx:119:3)
    at LoadingBoundary (layout-router.tsx:466:3)
    at ErrorBoundary (error-boundary.tsx:190:3)
    at InnerScrollAndFocusHandler (layout-router.tsx:289:3)
    at ScrollAndFocusHandler (layout-router.tsx:299:9)
    at RenderFromTemplateContext (render-from-template-context.tsx:8:10)
    at OuterLayoutRouter (layout-router.tsx:514:9)
    at body (<anonymous>)
    at html (<anonymous>)
    at RootLayout [Server] (<anonymous>)
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (redirect-boundary.tsx:48:5)
    at RedirectBoundary (redirect-boundary.tsx:79:9)
    at NotFoundErrorBoundary (not-found-boundary.tsx:33:5)
    at NotFoundBoundary (not-found-boundary.tsx:119:3)
    at DevRootNotFoundBoundary (dev-root-not-found-boundary.tsx:20:3)
    at ReactDevOverlay (ReactDevOverlay.tsx:110:3)
    at HotReload (hot-reloader-client.tsx:523:3)
    at Router (app-router.tsx:215:9)
    at ErrorBoundaryHandler (error-boundary.tsx:69:11)
    at ErrorBoundary (error-boundary.tsx:190:3)
    at AppRouter (app-router.tsx:632:3)
    at ServerRoot (app-index.tsx:176:32)
    at Root (app-index.tsx:204:17)

(2)
_1c1d36._.js:1058 Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `MapMenu`. See https://react.dev/link/warning-keys for more information. Error Component Stack
    at MapMenu (_1c1d36._.js:997:202)
    at div (<anonymous>)
    at div (<anonymous>)
    at Map (exports-mapbox.ts:56:16)
    at Map (map.tsx:34:31)
    at main (<anonymous>)
    at Sdui (sdui.tsx:23:31)
    at main (<anonymous>)
    at Home [Server] (<anonymous>)
    at InnerLayoutRouter (layout-router.tsx:324:3)
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (redirect-boundary.tsx:48:5)
    at RedirectBoundary (redirect-boundary.tsx:79:9)
    at NotFoundErrorBoundary (not-found-boundary.tsx:33:5)
    at NotFoundBoundary (not-found-boundary.tsx:119:3)
    at LoadingBoundary (layout-router.tsx:466:3)
    at ErrorBoundary (error-boundary.tsx:190:3)
    at InnerScrollAndFocusHandler (layout-router.tsx:289:3)
    at ScrollAndFocusHandler (layout-router.tsx:299:9)
    at RenderFromTemplateContext (render-from-template-context.tsx:8:10)
    at OuterLayoutRouter (layout-router.tsx:514:9)
    at body (<anonymous>)
    at html (<anonymous>)
    at RootLayout [Server] (<anonymous>)
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (redirect-boundary.tsx:48:5)
    at RedirectBoundary (redirect-boundary.tsx:79:9)
    at NotFoundErrorBoundary (not-found-boundary.tsx:33:5)
    at NotFoundBoundary (not-found-boundary.tsx:119:3)
    at DevRootNotFoundBoundary (dev-root-not-found-boundary.tsx:20:3)
    at ReactDevOverlay (ReactDevOverlay.tsx:110:3)
    at HotReload (hot-reloader-client.tsx:523:3)
    at Router (app-router.tsx:215:9)
    at ErrorBoundaryHandler (error-boundary.tsx:69:11)
    at ErrorBoundary (error-boundary.tsx:190:3)
    at AppRouter (app-router.tsx:632:3)
    at ServerRoot (app-index.tsx:176:32)
    at Root (app-index.tsx:204:17)
overrideMethod  @   hook.js:608
window.console.error    @   intercept-console-error.ts:44
validateExplicitKey @   react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:601
validateChildKeys   @   react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:549
jsxDEVImpl  @   react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:463
exports.jsxDEV  @   react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:673
MapMenu @   _1c1d36._.js:1058
react-stack-bottom-frame    @   react-dom-client.development.js:22348
renderWithHooks @   react-dom-client.development.js:5739
updateFunctionComponent @   react-dom-client.development.js:8000
beginWork   @   react-dom-client.development.js:9665
runWithFiberInDEV   @   react-dom-client.development.js:543
performUnitOfWork   @   react-dom-client.development.js:14996
workLoopSync    @   react-dom-client.development.js:14826
renderRootSync  @   react-dom-client.development.js:14806
performWorkOnRoot   @   react-dom-client.development.js:14301
performWorkOnRootViaSchedulerTask   @   react-dom-client.development.js:15852
performWorkUntilDeadline    @   scheduler.development.js:44

After that, i can input characters freely, without having any errors.
i have looked at multiple other post (this one seems the closest to my issue: Warning: Cannot update a component (`HotReload`) while rendering a different component (`Duck`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Duck`) and changed some lines to add useCallback and/or useEffect, but the problem persist
i use nextjs 15 with turbopack enabled, could it be the problem?
